# Sending array of object to WebService

Tags: java, android, web-services

I want to send an array of object to WebService, but I've got **RuntimeException: Cannot serialize [myClass]**. I tried many variations of creating a request, but none of them worked.

My class with calling WebService:

```
   SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, NAME);

    com.gt.android.webservice.model.LocationRecord[] table = convertObjects(locationRecords).toArray(new com.gt.android.webservice.model.LocationRecord[locationRecords.size()]);

    SoapObject root = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "locRecord");

    for (com.gt.android.webservice.model.LocationRecord i : table){
        root.addProperty("LocationRecord", i);
    }

    request.addSoapObject(root);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.dotNet = true;

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "LocationRecord", com.gt.android.webservice.model.LocationRecord.class);

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION + NAME, envelope);
... }
```

First: I have to convert from my list from one class to another one (just rewriting fields (to achieve a flat structure), later I try to make my root, add every field, add serialization, request, mapping and at least send my request. Here's webService structure:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <SynchonizeLocations xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <locRecord>
        <LocationRecord>
          <id>int</id>
          <logTime>dateTime</logTime>
          <message>string</message>
          <lt>double</lt>
          <lg>double</lg>
          <timestamp>dateTime</timestamp>
          <sessionBestLocation>boolean</sessionBestLocation>
          <number1>int</number1>
          <number2>int</number2>
        </LocationRecord>
        <LocationRecord>
          <id>int</id>
          <logTime>dateTime</logTime>
          <message>string</message>
          <lt>double</lt>
          <lg>double</lg>
          <timestamp>dateTime</timestamp>
          <sessionBestLocation>boolean</sessionBestLocation>
          <number1>int</number1>
          <number2>int</number2>
        </LocationRecord>
      </locRecord>
    </SynchonizeLocations>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Thanks for a help.

Comment: does your class implement serializable? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

Comment: @PhilippSander Yes, It does.

Comment: and do all the containing classes implement serializable too?

Comment: @PhilippSander Yup, every object implement serializable and it's still generating my error. I'm wondering about wrong creating XML tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) and convert your objects to strings.

1. Write a new object class that contains your objects array as a field.
2. Create your new object and load your array into it.
3. Convert your object into a String with Gson:

   Gson gson = new Gson();
      String json = gson.toJson(yourObject);

Example:

```
public class LocationRecordsHolder {

    public LocationRecord[] table;

    public LocationRecordsHolder(LocationRecord[] table) {
        this.table = table;
    }

    // Convert object to String
    public static String converToString(LocationRecordHolder obj) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(obj);
    }

    // Conver String to object
    public static LocationRecordHolder convertFromString(String json) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.fromJson(br, LocationRecordsHolder.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: But my WebService uses SOAP architecture, it,s ok to use JSON instead?

Comment: Check section 3 [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/).
String output will be in a Json structure